# Param color in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Cobalt2 theme in VS Code which is perfect for me. There is only one issue that I have with this theme, that would make me try changing it. Its the color of params in terminal, which is a dark blue on black - very hard to see. Does anyone know how to change this? What this element is called in a custom theme? Thanks for your help.

A small screenshot of what I mean:

Examples: `gulp serve --config, ng serve --port ...`

Its about the `--params` and their color

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to customize the text colors of the integrated terminal in VSCode, so there's no need to change the theme itself. You can simply overwrite the default colors.

Just add this line to your `settings.json`:

```json
"terminal.integrated.drawBoldTextInBrightColors": false
```

Then you'll be able to overwrite the default colors and change them to the colors you want to see instead:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.ansiBlack": "#50ff00",   //this overwrites black colors with green
    "terminal.ansiBlue": "#ff0000",    //this overwrites blue colors with red
    ...
}
```

Let's say you want to change the terminals black colors into another one (for example green), you'll have to asign `"#50ff00"` to `"terminal.ansiBlack"`. As you can see below, there are a few more colors you can change (make use of IntelliSense).

It should look like this:

[image]